# Combine unallocated space using KDE partition manager?

Tags: partition

See below screenshot and see that there are 2 unknown unallocated blocks.  How to combine the unallocated space using KDE partition manager?

[image]

@ktf, as requested:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders, total 1953525168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x823df1e4

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048      206847      102400    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2          206848  1186215955   593004554    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3      1195208704  1945712639   375251968   83  Linux
```

Comment: Being always very suspicios of fancy GUI tools, could you provide an output of `fdisk -l /dev/sda` ?

Comment: See above.  What does this tell you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for providing the fdisk-output. I feel a lot more confident seeing the actual sector numbers.

Back to your problem: You have only one option to combine the free space on your disk:

Use a tool that is capable of moving partitions physically - the 3rd partition has to be moved up to fill the gap to the 2nd partition. Since this is the Linux partition, **you cannot do that while this Linux is running** (!). I see two NTFS partitions in front, so I assume there is a Windows OS installed. Windows shouldn't be affected since its partitions don't have to be moved, so I'd look for partition magic or similar tool for Windows.

Part of the problem is that you already used up three of the four primary partitions, so you cannot create a 4th primary partition as gap-filler **and** an extended partition for the rest of the disk. This removes the option to use the logical volume manager to combine two partitions.

Comment: I was thinkin' Live CD, using a partition manager to resize-manipulate to the desired effect?  I would combine unallocated 1 with sda3, then shave off the same amount on the other end of sda3.  The new unallocated should be automatically merged with unallocated 2 in the original screenshot.  Does this make sense?  A bit manual and tedious, but if it works it'd save me having to use a third party, possibly proprietary partitioner...

Comment: Using a Live-CD may be used also. You may want to check this out: http://gparted.sourceforge.net/ They used to offer a Live-CD.

Comment: Had an OpenSUSE Live Gnome 11.4 CD handy but the unallocated space wasn't showing up in the native partitioner, and I couldn't resize the preceding or following partitions to swallow up that unallocated space...  How does one explain this?

Comment: Sorry for not knowing if that particular partition tool is capable of moving partitions - with the KDE Partition manager you should be able to do this: Click on partition sda3 then on the *Resize/Move Partition* shortcut button. A dialog should appear where you adjust the right and left edges of the partition image with your mouse until free space before (and after) becomes zero. Click *OK* and then *Apply*. If there is no resize/move option it could be that on this particular Live CD an old version of the partition manager is installed or some underlying tools are missing.

Comment: Ended up using GParted with Ubuntu Live CD.  Important (and inconvenient) thing to note was that I can't seem to merge non-contiguous partitions directly.  You have to merge it into the intervening partitions and carve off the equivalent space at the end, then merge once the unallocated spaces are back-to-back.  That is always how I've done it.  Was hoping someone knew a more direct way that doesn't involve proprietary tools.  But for now that is the solution I have run with.  Cheerio ktf.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/gparted.html

The guide for GParted mentions that this area could very well be a complicated sector containing any number of different things. It's rather odd to see that though, especially with no mount point. It'd be roughly the size of a swap partition, which might be part of it.

Comment: GParted is not the native partitioner of KDE - I have noticed compatibility issues - it doesn't even launch properly in KDE for some reason.  Can you please stick to KDE partitioner?  Thanks...